# <input type="file> does not work in Corona SDK Android web app

Tags: android, coronasdk

I created an android app with Corona SDK, that just opens the mobile version of my website in the app. I only did this because I don't know Java, and I am not able to fully program an app from scratch. It opens the website fine, and looks great, but when I click the "Choose File" button, that on my site is `<input type="file">`, nothing happens. The little button gets pushed, but no dialog shows to open a file. To open the site in my Corona App, I am using `native.newWebView("foobar.com")`. In the documentation for that function, it does say: **"Native web views are not part of the OpenGL canvas and do not obey the display object hierarchy, so they will always appear in front of normal display objects including images, text, and vector objects."** Is this the problem? I want the file open dialog to be able to open in my app. 
(On the actual mobile version of my site (in android web browser), the file dialog does open correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously trying to access external storage. Try a build.setting like this.

```
settings = 
{
    orientation = 
    {
        default = "portrait",
        supported = { "portrait" },
    },
    android =
    {
        usesPermissions =
        {
            "android.permission.INTERNET",
            "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
            "android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE",
        },
        usesFeatures =
        {
            { name = "android.hardware.location", required = false },
            { name = "android.hardware.location.gps", required = false },
            { name = "android.hardware.location.network", required = false },
        },
    },
    iphone =
    {
        plist =
        {
            CFBundleIconFile = "Icon.png",
            CFBundleIconFiles =
            {
                "Icon.png", 
                "Icon@2x.png", 
                "Icon-60.png",
                "Icon-60@2x.png",
                "Icon-72.png", 
                "Icon-72@2x.png",
                "Icon-76.png",
                "Icon-76@2x.png", 
                "Icon-Small.png", 
                "Icon-Small@2x.png",
                "Icon-Small-40.png",
                "Icon-Small-40@2x.png",
                "Icon-Small-50.png", 
                "Icon-Small-50@2x.png", 
            },
        },
    },
}
```